# Bad Performance of PMML Evaluator

Tags: regression, model-evaluation, pmml

I have been working on a proof-of-concept setup of evaluating various PMML-based models. Specifically, I've been using the JPMML evaluator (https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator), which is in Java, calling it from Scala. Among several toy models I have been tinkering with, I created a PMML file for a linear regression model that takes in 10,000 boolean arguments (each one with the value of 1 or 0) and then evaluates the dot-product of the 10,000-long vector of weights (defined in the PMML file under the  tag) with the 10,000-long vector of inputs, only one of the entries being 1 and the rest being 0. (Essentially, this amounts to a lookup of the weight by the associated parameter.)

Surprisingly, I discovered that it took about 2 seconds (!) for the PMML evaluator to evaluate such a simple thing--and that, with the PMML already pre-parsed when calling the evaluate() method! Any suggestions on why?

The PMML file for 10,000 parameters is, obviously, rather long. A similar file with only 10 parameters is attached:

```
<PMML version="4.2" xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2">
    <Header description="Generalized Linear Regression Model">
        <Application name="Test Model" version="1.0"/>
    </Header>
    <DataDictionary numberOfFields="11">
        <DataField name="score" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
        <DataField name="1" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="2" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="3" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="4" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="5" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="6" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="7" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="8" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="9" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
        <DataField name="10" optype="continuous" dataType="integer"/>
    </DataDictionary>
    <GeneralRegressionModel modelName="Test Model" modelType="generalizedLinear" functionName="regression" algorithmName="glm" distribution="normal" linkFunction="logit">
        <MiningSchema>
            <MiningField name="score" usageType="predicted"/>
            <MiningField name="1" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="2" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="3" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="4" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="5" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="6" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="7" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="8" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="9" usageType="active"/>
            <MiningField name="10" usageType="active"/>
        </MiningSchema>
        <Output>
            <OutputField name="score" feature="predictedValue"/>
        </Output>
        <ParameterList>
            <Parameter name="score_param" label="(Intercept)"/>
            <Parameter name="1" label="1"/>
            <Parameter name="2" label="2"/>
            <Parameter name="3" label="3"/>
            <Parameter name="4" label="4"/>
            <Parameter name="5" label="5"/>
            <Parameter name="6" label="6"/>
            <Parameter name="7" label="7"/>
            <Parameter name="8" label="8"/>
            <Parameter name="9" label="9"/>
            <Parameter name="10" label="10"/>
        </ParameterList>
        <CovariateList>
            <Predictor name="1"/>
            <Predictor name="2"/>
            <Predictor name="3"/>
            <Predictor name="4"/>
            <Predictor name="5"/>
            <Predictor name="6"/>
            <Predictor name="7"/>
            <Predictor name="8"/>
            <Predictor name="9"/>
            <Predictor name="10"/>
        </CovariateList>
        <PPMatrix>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="1" parameterName="1"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="2" parameterName="2"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="3" parameterName="3"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="4" parameterName="4"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="5" parameterName="5"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="6" parameterName="6"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="7" parameterName="7"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="8" parameterName="8"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="9" parameterName="9"/>
            <PPCell value="1" predictorName="10" parameterName="10"/>
        </PPMatrix>
        <ParamMatrix>
            <PCell parameterName="score_param" df="1" beta="0"/>
            <PCell parameterName="1" df="1" beta="0.9011255655311873"/>
            <PCell parameterName="2" df="1" beta="0.9213215091770879"/>
            <PCell parameterName="3" df="1" beta="0.3623167363776304"/>
            <PCell parameterName="4" df="1" beta="0.2611235035721956"/>
            <PCell parameterName="5" df="1" beta="0.22401829251069683"/>
            <PCell parameterName="6" df="1" beta="0.47040738391130854"/>
            <PCell parameterName="7" df="1" beta="0.37109087550595976"/>
            <PCell parameterName="8" df="1" beta="0.6147636550988892"/>
            <PCell parameterName="9" df="1" beta="0.2719585907349067"/>
            <PCell parameterName="10" df="1" beta="0.1219419730278416"/>
        </ParamMatrix>
    </GeneralRegressionModel>
</PMML>
```

Comment: This issue has been addressed in JPMML-Evaluator versions 1.2.3 and newer. The execution time for a model with 10'000 parameters should be reduced about 100 times now, from 2 sec to 0.02 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, you should direct this question directly to JPMML-Evaluator's issue tracker. It probably involves rather specific and low-level technical explanation.

A logistic regression model with 10'000 boolean arguments (in PMML terms `active fields`), especially if there is only one argument set to `true` at a time, is clearly an edge case. You shouldn't blame a general-purpose library for performing badly here.

Maybe you can revisit your arguments - for example, replacing ten thousand bit fields with a single bitstring field?

With more typical logistic regression models (say, 10 to 30 arguments) you can reasonably expect high tens of thousands scorings per second.

Comment: I beg to differ. Looking at the PMML schema, all I see is vectors, matrices, and maps of various kinds--nothing that couldn't be placed in constant-time access structures upon parsing. I see no inherent reason why a PMML evaluator shouldn't scale well with the number of parameters. After all, for how long will our models be typically limited to "say, 10 to 30 arguments?"

Comment: Imagine a logistic model that has 10 categorical variables, and each categorical variable is 50 levels "deep". This model would work fine with JPMML-Evaluator.  You could then "flatten" this model to produce a new logistic model that has 500 boolean variables (at any time, there would be 10 bits on and 490 bits off). As you have just proven, this model does not work so fine anymore with JPMML-Evaluator.

Comment: Once you become aware of this limitation, what would you do? I can think of two good options. First, re-encode your arguments as categorical variables. Second, extend the JPMML-Evaluator library with a subclass of GeneralRegressionModelEvaluator class that contains smart optimizations for handling boolean lists.